# can't exit Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

once in every 5-10 times i run my iOS code with XCode- on the simulator this is what happens:

1. the program doesn't run
2. the stop button is press-able but when i press it it doesn't do anything

3.I can't exit Xcode! the only way to exit is by force quitting Xcode

I don't even know what printouts or code to share because it doesnt seem to do with the code at all.
this happens after compiling successfully, the simulator is showing the splash screen (and not continuing to run the program) 
and the log shows:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1822) (Sun Aug  5 03:00:42 UTC 2012)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 4411.
```

I'm using OS X version 10.8.2 and xcode version 4.5.2, but the problem also happened when i was running older versions of XCode and OS X.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project? Removing all derived data? Running a new template project? Resetting the simulator's content? Reinstalling Xcode?

Comment: Check in Activity Monitor to see if your program is actually being executed? Maybe you have an infinite loop somewhere set up in a way that ignores the signal handler that XCode uses to stop your program.

Comment: @DrummerB Covered most of the bases, but don't forget how miraculous a reboot can be, cough cough once every month or two!

Comment: @DrummerB- i did clean, removed derived data, i reboot every day and this is still happening... I updated xcode and the OS ...

Answer (score 1):

Xcode and the Simulator are not the only processes that spawn when you run your application.  In the activity monitor, you'll see a third process called "Simulator Bridge", which has always had a nasty reputation of sticking around as a zombie process.  After you kill Xcode and the Simulator itself, kill the simulator bridge process and fire up Xcode again.